# Cardinality, surjective, injective function of complex variable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

Let $A = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{mod}(z)  \ge 1 \}$ and $B= \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : z \ne 0\} $.

Does there exists an injective function from $A$ to $B$ or $B$ to $A$?

Does there exist a surjective function from $A$ to $B$ or $B$ to $A$?

I think it depends on cardinality of $A$ and $B$, but how to determine I am not sure. Does inversion function $f(z)=\dfrac1z$ may be useful in someway?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for an arbitrary surjection (only cardinality matters then) or a holomorphic surjection (much more interesting)?

Comment: What is ${\rm mod}(z)$?

Comment: Mod(z) is just modulus of z.

Comment: Yes sir, I was asking from cardinality point of view, but analytic f(z) would be more interesting. Help please

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this problem is related to cardinality: Two sets A and B are said to be of same cardinality if and only if a bijection between them exists.

For your problem, all four desired functions exist. To show that, there are at least three different approaches:

1. You can show that an injection $f_1:A\to B$ and an injection $g_1:B\to A$ exist. From $f_1$ you can conclude $|A|\leq|B|$ and from $g_1$ you can conclude $|B|\leq|A|$. So $|A|=|B|$ and a bijection $h:A\to B$ exists. $h^{-1}:B\to A$ then is a bijection, too.
2. You can show that a surjection $f_2:A\to B$ and a surjection $g_2:B\to A$ exist. From $f_2$ you can conclude $|B|\leq|A|$ and from $g_2$ you can conclude $|A|\leq|B|$. So $|A|=|B|$ and a bijection $h:A\to B$ exists. $h^{-1}:B\to A$ then is a bijection, too.
3. You can show that a bijection $f:A\to B$ exists. $f^{-1}:B\to A$ then is a bijection, too.

We proceed by approach 1:

- Example for an injective function from $A$ to $B$:
  $$f_{1}:=\begin{cases}
  A & \to B\\
  z & \mapsto z
  \end{cases}$$
- Example for an injective function from $B$ to $A$:
  $$g_{1}:=\begin{cases}
  B & \to A\\
  r\cdot e^{i\varphi} & \mapsto(r+1)\cdot e^{i\varphi}
  \end{cases}$$

You can directly give a bijective function (approach 3), too:
$$f:=\begin{cases}
B & \to A\\
z & \mapsto\frac{\left|z\right|+1}{\left|z\right|}z\quad\text{(if }z\neq1\text{)}\\
z & \mapsto z^{2}\quad\text{(if }z=1,\arg(z)\in\left[0,\pi\right)\text{)}\\
z & \mapsto2z^{2}\quad\text{(if }z=1,\arg(z)\in\left[\pi,2\pi\right)\text{)}
\end{cases}$$
(**EDIT 1:** Corrected the answer.

**EDIT 2:** Added approach 3.)

Comment: I just found out that I read the problem statement wrong -- I read $z\neq 1$ instead of $z\neq 0$ in the definition on $B$. So my answer is wrong for your problem statement. Sorry about that. Nevertheless, such functions exist.

Comment: I just corrected my mistake - answer should be okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sets geometrically:

- set $A$ is a unit circle plus its exterior,
- set $B$ is the whole complex plane wihtout the zero point,

As $A\subset B$, the identity function injects $A$ into $B$.

On the other hand you can inject $B$ into $A$ just by shifting each point away from the $0$: 
$$z\mapsto z\cdot\frac{|z|+1}{|z|}$$
Note, however, this function is not surjective: its image is an exterior of the unit circle, without the circle itself.

By the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), when there exist two injections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, then there exists a bijection between the two sets, hence both sets are equipollent (and obviously there exists a surjection: the bijection is a surjection).